# Explicit struct layout with Guid

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling, .net-framework-version

I'm trying to have an explicit struct layout where I am reinterpreting a byte array as guids.  This works fine when running in 32 bit for both .net 4.7 and .net 4.7.2.  But when you run it in 64 bit it works in .NET 4.7, but doesn't seem to work in .NET 4.7.2.  Is this code invalid or could this be a bug in .NET?

[UPDATE]: Tested on a few more configurations.  Works on 4.6.2 and 4.7, but doesn't work on 4.7.1 and 4.7.2.

[UPDATE 2]: Looking at the disassembly.  In 64 bit that assign results in a no-op.  So I think that's pretty clear that it's a bug in .net:

32bit disassembly:

```
TestStruct t = new TestStruct();
03010480  lea         edi,[ebp-58h]
03010483  xorps       xmm0,xmm0
03010486  movq        mmword ptr [edi],xmm0
0301048A  movq        mmword ptr [edi+8],xmm0
0301048F  movq        mmword ptr [edi+10h],xmm0
03010494  movq        mmword ptr [edi+18h],xmm0

t.Guid1 = Guid.NewGuid();
03010499  lea         eax,[ebp-58h]
0301049C  mov         dword ptr [ebp-64h],eax
0301049F  lea         ecx,[ebp-74h]
030104A2  call        723628F0
030104A7  mov         edi,dword ptr [ebp-64h]
030104AA  lea         esi,[ebp-74h]
030104AD  movq        xmm0,mmword ptr [esi]
030104B1  movq        mmword ptr [edi],xmm0
030104B5  movq        xmm0,mmword ptr [esi+8]
030104BA  movq        mmword ptr [edi+8],xmm0

t.Guid2 = t.Guid1;
030104BF  lea         edi,[ebp-58h]
030104C2  add         edi,10h
030104C5  lea         esi,[ebp-58h]
030104C8  movq        xmm0,mmword ptr [esi]
030104CC  movq        mmword ptr [edi],xmm0
030104D0  movq        xmm0,mmword ptr [esi+8]
030104D5  movq        mmword ptr [edi+8],xmm0
```

64bit disassembly:

```
TestStruct t = new TestStruct();
00007FFB054604B2  lea         rcx,[rbp+78h]
00007FFB054604B6  vxorpd      xmm0,xmm0,xmm0
00007FFB054604BB  vmovdqu     xmmword ptr [rcx],xmm0
00007FFB054604C0  vmovdqu     xmmword ptr [rcx+10h],xmm0

t.Guid1 = Guid.NewGuid();
00007FFB054604C6  lea         rcx,[rbp+78h]
00007FFB054604CA  mov         qword ptr [rbp+68h],rcx
00007FFB054604CE  lea         rcx,[rbp+58h]
00007FFB054604D2  call        00007FFB639BE8C0
00007FFB054604D7  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+68h]
00007FFB054604DB  vmovdqu     xmm0,xmmword ptr [rbp+58h]
00007FFB054604E1  vmovdqu     xmmword ptr [rax],xmm0

t.Guid2 = t.Guid1;
00007FFB054604E6  nop
```

Code to reproduce:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = SIZE)]
internal unsafe struct TestStruct
{
    public const int SIZE = 32;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private fixed byte _data[SIZE];

    [FieldOffset(0), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 16)]
    public Guid Guid1;

    [FieldOffset(16), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 16)]
    public Guid Guid2;
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        TestStruct t = new TestStruct();
        t.Guid1 = Guid.NewGuid();
        t.Guid2 = t.Guid1;

        if (t.Guid1 != t.Guid2)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Guids aren't equal");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say _doesn't seem to work_? What happens when you run this?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear.  I would not expect that exception to be thrown.  I would expect Guid1 to be equal to Guid2.  But when I run it on a machine with .net 4.7.2 Guid1 is empty and that exception gets thrown.  When I run it on a machine on 4.7 that exception does not get thrown and works how you would expect.

Comment: FieldOffset(17)  -- shouldn't that be 16?

Comment: I ran this on `.NET 4.7.2` and it shows them as equal for me.

Comment: You're right @DaveS, I'll modify the question it should be FieldOffset(16), but I'm still showing them as unequal

Comment: Ran on a PC with .NET 4.6.1 as well, but can't reproduce. Maybe upload your project to git or something?

Comment: @Sach, so it does work if I select "Prefer 32-bit" in the build configuration, but if I uncheck "Prefer 32-bit" it fails.  So it seems to work in 32 bit, but not 64 bit.  I'll try to upload repro to git shortly

Comment: OK no need to upload, I managed to reproduce the problem. So, either if you set `Platform Target` to `Any` and check `Prefer 32-bit`, or simply select `x86` as the platform target, it says equal. Otherwise, `Guid2` is all zeroes.

Comment: @Sach, I modified my question to include the part about 32 bit vs 64 bit.  So I guess my original question remains.  Whether or not this a bug in 4.7.2 or illegal code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if it's a bug, but doing this fixes the problem even in 64-bit platform: `t.Guid2 = new Guid(t.Guid1.ToByteArray());`

Comment: @Sach, sure there are tons of ways around this and I made my example as simple as possible.  But this works in 64 bit for .net 4.7 but not 4.7.2.  So either it's not valid code and I was relying on undefined behavior previously or it's a bug in 4.7.2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173095/discussion-between-sach-and-todd-hansen).

Comment: @Sach, so the disassembly for 64 bit results in nop, whereas it does not for 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in RyuJIT and resolved with the following pull request.

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/17971

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem could be related with the FieldOffset. FieldOffset(16) is displacing the byte array.
If you encapsulate the field and use a property you shouldn't have the problem.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = SIZE)]
internal unsafe struct TestStruct
{
    public const int SIZE = 32;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public fixed byte _data[SIZE];

    [FieldOffset(0), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 16)]
    private Guid guid1;

    [FieldOffset(16), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 16)]
    private Guid guid2;

    public Guid Guid1 { get => guid1; set => guid1 = value; }
    public Guid Guid2 { get => guid2; set => guid2 = value; }
}
```

Comment: You're correct, this does work and is a possible work around along with `t.Guid2 = new Guid(t.Guid1.ToByteArray());` as was suggested above.  That still doesn't explain why my code used to work but doesn't under 4.7.2 and if there is something wrong with it, or 4.7.2